# What is the best way to align views on the right in a Linear Horizontal layout?

Tags: android-linearlayout, text-alignment, margins

If the views on the left aren't all the same length. Let's say you have the following:

Horizontal layout 1(Name: Mary)
layout 2(Age:     28)
layout 3(Height:      5'4)

I want the views on the right to be aligned so that the first letter of every text on the right is at the same spot,e.g I know how to align the textViews on the left. Here, "Age" is right below "Name" and right above "Height". Now, I want the same for the views on the right: letter "M" right above "2" and "5".

So, if below I specify margins for the first textView, it will work if another text view on the left has the same number of letters, e.g."Date". What should I do if the textView on the left is longer? Thank you in advance.

P.S. To moderators: I found a few similar answers but none that address this specific issue.

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:text="Name"/>

                 <TextView
                    android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:text="Mary"/>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are approaching this the wrong way.
Try using nested LiniarLayouts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:text="Name"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:text="Age"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:text="Height"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:text="Mary"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:text="28"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:text="5'4"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It works. The views are aligned now. Except the views aren't aligned horizontally. Also, if there are more than one lines(words) on the right - say a list view - do we add padding to make them aligned with the views on the left?

Comment: in order to do that you have to use android:layout_weight. see here https://blog.stylingandroid.com/layout-weights-part-1/

Comment: Weights aren't recommended inside nested layouts. Would it be better to rearrange the code and have several horizontal nested views? For example, "Name:" and "Mary" in one horizontal layout, etc. for other views and enclose all of them in a linear vertical layout?